# Implement Yosemite Reminders/Notes/Messages/Contacts style windows

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-interface, osx-yosemite

How do I create a Yosemite Reminders/Notes/Messages/Contacts style window? Specifically, the traffic lights are on the left pane of a split view, while the right pane takes up the whole space including the title bar area. See the attached screenshots.

[image: Reminders][image: Notes][image: Messages][image: Contacts]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a combination of two new `NSWindow` options.

1. Include `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` in your window's `styleMask` to make the content view of the window stretch up behind the title/toolbar.
2. Enable the `titlebarAppearsTransparent` property to disable rendering of the translucent title/toolbar material so that the content view shows up in the title/toolbar area without getting blurred.