# Fantastical 2-style sidebar

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, sidebar, nsoutlineview

How does one create sidebar in the style of Fantastical 2?

[image]

Specifically, these sidebars run all the way to the top of the window, and the horizontal titlebar divider doesn't exist.

It is also the style used in the upcoming Reeder 3:

[image]

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916954/implement-yosemite-reminders-notes-messages-contacts-style-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to create an official answer. You found the solution yourself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916954/implement-yosemite-reminders-notes-messages-contacts-style-windows).